TV series where a prison inmate uses a Queen of Hearts playing card as a calling card
I'm looking to identify the TV series where a prison inmate uses a Queen of Hearts playing card as a calling card. In the series, an executive of a bank (I think) is framed and sent to prison for two years. He uses the prison as a school by listening to inmates sent in for various crimes.
With the knowledge he learns in prison, he brings the people who framed him to justice. The series continues with him using these skills to help other people who had similar situations.
He always left a calling card—the "Queen of Hearts" playing card. I watched this TV series back in the late '70s–early '80s. It was set in the USA. I believe that it aired probably 2 years before Cannon.

Please review these Tips for asking Movie/TV Identification questions and [edit] any additional information into your question.

When did you watch this TV series?

Late 70s early 80s.

https://community-imdb.sprinklr.com/conversations/i-need-to-know/name-of-a-tv-series-with-the-main-characters-calling-card-is-a-queen-of-herarts-playing-card/617ec975cd6ade3bf41d56a7

Where was it set? UK/USA/somewhere else? Can you recall the name of the principal character or who played him?

Set in the USA.  I belive that it aired probably 2 years before Cannon

Was set in the US. I can't remember very much else.

The name of the show was Sword Of Justice (1978)

Upon his release, he decided to turn the tables on such above-the-law criminals as he blamed for his misfortunes by fighting them at their own game, à la It Takes a Thief, and using a unique way to leave his message: the "3" from a deck of cards, indicating how many years he spent behind bars. On these cards would be a written warning for the criminal(s).


You should mark your answer as accepted
